Someone said my WhatsApp status was online, but I didn't touch my phone
I wasn't using my phone, let alone my WhatsApp at the time, and my SO called me via video call. I didn't answer, but she said the status said "online" and clearly it did so. She screenshot it and I'm confused because I wasn't touching my phone and it wasn't turned on at all.
Is it a problem related to my phone or internet or something that caused my last seen as "online"?
This is becoming unsettling for me and her because it happened multiple times, and neither of us knows why, and I felt guilty because it made her think about it the wrong way. I'd like to experiment with this, but in the meantime, any help would be much appreciated.

Are you using WhatsApp Desktop?

I don't recall seeing a status anywhere.  I just tested it, I can not find any status visible when I make a video or a non-video call.  The only thing that is visible is a message that you can put in, in your profile.
By default it says something like "Hello I am using WhatsApp".  I think you have changed that message to say "online".

The status "online" or "last seen" can be seen in each individual's chat, not call.
